# Implementing transaction on multiple database mongodb cluster [node mongoose]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on an application where I have to use three mongodb database from three different   clusters. I have to implement transaction on them. I found solution for multiple database but in the same cluster... Is it possible to implement transaction for multiple database in different different cluster or located in different server?

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to find a build in solution from mongodb but you can implement your own workflow with multiple transaction providers. I may suggest you to check the [multiple-transaction-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiple-transaction-manager) library for orchestrating your transactions.

The test case is like follows;

```
    const txnMngr: MultiTxnMngr = new MultiTxnMngr();

    const mongoContext = new MongoContext(theMongoose);

    // Add first step
    mongoContext.addFunctionTask(txnMngr, (mongoose, txn, task) => studentModel.create([{ sid: 1, "name": "Kevin" }], { session: txn }));

    // Add second step
    mongoContext.addFunctionTask(txnMngr, (mongoose, txn, task) => studentModel.create([{ sid: 2, "name": "Stuart" }], { session: txn }));

    // Uncomment next line if you want to test rollback scenario 
    // mongoContext.addFunctionTask(txnMngr, (mongoose, txn, task) => studentModel.create([{ sid: 2, "name": "Bob" }], { session: txn }));

    // Add control step
    let controlTask = mongoContext.addFunctionTask(txnMngr, (mongoose, txn, task) => studentModel.findOne({ sid: 1 }).session(txn).exec());

    await txnMngr.exec()
```

In your case, you can initialize multiple mongo contexts to manage multiple transactions.